# Multiple Buttons If Else Condition

Tags: vb.net

I need some help to make a condition that if a user will select or click more than 1 button, there would be a MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process") appeared.... The scenario is this: I have 5 buttons(A3, A4, A5, A6, A7) and on the code below shows that if a user will select any of the buttons, the BackColor of the Button will be Red and so IF a user will select or click again as the users second choice, THEN there would a MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process") appeared. What code is appropriate for the Condition? I will really appreciate any HELP ..... Thank You so MUCH!!!:'(

```
Private Sub A3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles A3.Click, A4.Click, A5.Click, A6.Click, A7.Click

    sender.BackColor = Color.Red

    If sender ......  Then
          MsgBox()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a `RadioButton` or a `CheckBox` with the `Appearance` property set to `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim btn As New Button
    Dim haveFound As Boolean = False
    For index = 3 To 7
        btn = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("A" + index.ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(), Button)
        If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process")
            haveFound = True
        End If
    Next
    If haveFound = False Then
        sender.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
```

This is a way you could do it.

Basically it searches through every single element for if it has a red background then outputs your message and changes a Boolean variable 'haveFound' to true.  If this variable is still false at the end of its search then it will set the back color to red.

Have Fun!

EDIT: To add the 'B' set of buttons between 3 and 7 (Remember to add the handler for them

```
    Dim btn As New Button
    Dim haveFound As Boolean = False
    For index = 3 To 7
        btn = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("A" + index.ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(), Button)
        If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process")
            haveFound = True
        End If
        btn = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("B" + index.ToString, True).FirstOrDefault(), Button)
        If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process")
            haveFound = True
        End If
    Next
    If haveFound = False Then
        sender.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
```

Comment: Thank You so much Sir RedLaser .... it did worked ... THANK YOU so so so MUCH .... :'(

Comment: Hello Sir RedLaser, ahmmm what if aside from A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 buttons, i will add B3.Click, B4.Click, B5.Click, B6.Click, B7.Click .... what code should I put?

Comment: I'll assume they are all buttons then put them in the handler space then repeat the contents of the For Loop again but change 'Find("A" + index.ToString, True) to 'Find("B" + index.ToString, True)'.  I'll put that all into an edit of my original post for you

Comment: Thank You so Much Sir RedLaser .... :'(
I really appreciate the help sir ... Thank You ... :')

Answer (score 1):

So lets say you have 5 buttons on your form to let the user select 1 from.

First make a button click event. "Private Sub Check_Button(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)"
Then add the click even of all the buttons you want to use to the to the "Check_Button"
[image]

In this event you need to do 3 things.

1. Check if the user wants to deselect his selected button."maybe he changed his mind"
   In the first part i check if the sender.backColor = Color.Red"If yes make it white"
2. Check if there is already a buttons selected.
   In the second part i make a list(of Buttons)"With the buttons you want to use"
   And use a for loop to check if there is a button with a red background.
   If it finds one it will make BError = True
3. Select a button.
   In the last part it will check if the BError is True or False.
   If its True The msgbox will show and if its False it wil make the BackGround collor of the sender red.

   ```
   Private Sub Check_Button(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles A5.Click, A4.Click, A3.Click, A2.Click, A1.Click

   Dim BSender As Button = CType(sender, Control)
   If BSender.BackColor = Color.Red Then
       BSender.BackColor = Color.White
       Return
   End If

   Dim Buttons As New List(Of Button) From {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5}'Buttons you want to check
   Dim BError As Boolean = False
   For i = 0 To Buttons.Count - 1
       If Buttons(i).BackColor = Color.Red Then
           BError = True
       End If
   Next
   If BError = False Then
       sender.BackColor = Color.Red
   Else
       MsgBox("You can only select one seat for every Process")
   End If

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: THANK YOU so much Sir Creator .... i really appreciate the help ... THANK YOU so so much ... :'(